# Using Apache, how can I redirect a subfolder of a site to a subdomain but redirect everything but that subfolder to the primary domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the same website running on Apache at two different subdomains using vhosts.

`www.vhost1.com`

`www.vhost2.com`

Whenever someone accesses a particular subfolder on `www.vhost1.com`, I want the user to be redirected to that same subfolder on `www.vhost2.com`.

Example:
User accesses `www.vhost1.com/my-special-folder`
User should be redirected to `www.vhost2.com/my-special-folder`

And whenever someone is on `www.vhost2.com` and accesses anything except that subfolder, I want the user to be redirected to `www.vhost1.com/any-other-url`

Example:
User accesses `www.vhost2.com/any-other-url`
User should be redirected to `www.vhost1.com/any-other-url`

Also, if the user accesses `www.vhost2.com` (with no path), the user should be redirected to `www.vhost1.com`

Example:
User accesses `www.vhost2.com`
User should be redirected to `www.vhost1.com`

I've tried several different Apache redirect rules and have gotten several of the scenarios to work, but I can't get them all to work at the same time.

Because of the server configuration, I must perform the redirects using a .htaccess file.

What should the Apache rules be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess of both domains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?vhost1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my-special-folder)(/.*)?$ http://www.vhost2.com/$1$2 [L,NC,NE.R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?vhost2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!my-special-folder/).*)$ http://www.vhost1.com/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava. I should have been more clear. The document root for both vhosts is the same folder, so it's the same .htaccess file that I would be editing. Should I be able to place both of those snippets in the same .htaccess file and it still work?

Comment: Yes definitely both of these rewrite rules can be placed in the same .htaccess file and both will work independently of each other since they both have different `RewriteCond` to target different host names.

Comment: I tried to implement this but I ended up with a redirect loop. I suspect it has something to do with the site being Drupal and there being quite a few additional redirects in the .htaccess file that Drupal uses by default. So I ended up implementing the solution in PHP instead. I realize it won't be as fast, but I had a deadline. I really appreciate your input, and hopefully your solution will help others.

Comment: If you have other rules then keep these rules before all other rules. Also please consider marking as accepted to give this Q&A more visibility.

Comment: I did have these rules at the top and Chrome still gave me the error about a redirect loop.